Can one LinkedIn App's OAUTH token be utilized for multiple website's server-side tagging set up?
Question 1: we are an agency, and we help people set up web and server-side tracking. While submitting the request form for the LinkedIn Conversion API product, we selected the "Agency" checkbox. Can we use our app to generate tokens for our clients' server-side tracking setup, or does each client have to go through the same approval process if they want to opt for LinkedIn CAPI?
Question 2: As an agency, if we are using the same approved app for the upcoming server-side setup we do for our clients, should we use the same refresh token or regenerate a new one for each client's setup?
Per my understanding, an app will have one active token at a time. Please correct me if I'm wrong. If we generate a new token, the old one will become useless.
So I am currently seeking support for the best approach. Can anyone please confirm keeping all clients' setups using one app and one token is fine Or what can be the approach in this scenario?
I applied for Conversion API access by filling out the given form and as a company, we selected all three options: agency, data advertiser, and data provider. The request has been approved and we now have access.
